# How to use uniq in Rails with respect to a column

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model with name Employee.rb
I want to select all inside Employee table but the without repetition of employeeID
for eg.

```
id  emp_name employeeID shop_id
 1    name1     13        4
 2    name2     15        5
 3    name3     16        4
 4    name2     15        3
 5    name2     15        4
 6    name4     18        6
```

If this is the table structure i want to get an active record relation like this

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Employee id: 1, emp_name: name1, employeeID: 13, shop_id: 4>, #<Employee id: 2, emp_name: name2, employeeID: 15, shop_id: 5>, #<Employee id: 3, emp_name: name3, employeeID: 16, shop_id: 4>, #<Employee id: 6, emp_name: name4, employeeID: 18, shop_id: 6>>
```

where the employeeID is unique. wont repeat

Is there any single line command to do this in Ruby on Rails.Pls help

Comment: Try `Employee.group('employeeID')`, this should do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What so far I got is:

```
Employee.all.uniq_by(&:employee_id)
```

You can also use where clause:

```
Employee.where(name: 'name2').uniq_by(&:employee_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Postgres you can do

```
Employee.select('DISTINCT ON (employeeID) *')
```